# Re-route request to domain without subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, blogs

I currently have my blog at `blog.flohei.de`. I'd like to drop the `blog` and run everything at `flohei.de` directly. Old links to `blog.flohei.de/foo/bar.html` should then automatically redirected or mapped to `flohei.de/foo/bar.html`. I think this is possible using a `.htaccess` file, right? But how do I exactly do this? Where do I put that file? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file of `blog.flohei.de`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.(flohei\.de)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks! Do you have a link to a reference? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes sure this is [Apache reference manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)